# How to extract some elements randomly from two dimensional list? / Python

Tags: python, list, random

I have a 6 x 6 list.

```
mylist = [[i for i in range(6)] for j in range(6)]
```

And I want to extract some elements randomly and then, I want to change that elements to other character (for example, 'x').
But, I don't want to use numpy, because of some reason related to library and function that I am using.

```
mylist = [
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

randomed_list = [
[0, 1, x, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, x, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, x, 3, 4, 5],
[0, x, x, 3, x, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, x, x]]
```

How can I do?
Thanks! :-)

Comment: Use `random.randrange(0, 6)`  or `random.randint(0, 5)` to get random indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution of your problem, I hope that it will help you.

```
import random
    
    mylist = [
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
    
    def random_num():
        
        i = -1
        
        while True:
            
            if i == len(mylist[i])-1:
                
                break
                
            for item in mylist[i]:
                
                i += 1
                
                random_number = random.choice(mylist[i])
                
                mylist[i][random_number] = "x"
    
    
    random_num()
    
    for item in mylist:`enter code here`
        
        print(item)
    
    # Output -->
    # ['x', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    # [0, 1, 2, 'x', 4, 5]
    # [0, 1, 2, 'x', 4, 5]
    # [0, 1, 2, 3, 'x', 5]
    # [0, 1, 2, 3, 'x', 5]
    # [0, 1, 2, 3, 'x', 5]
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing. I really really really appreciate of you.

Comment: I am happy that You like my work. If there is any suggestions related to my code so I can improve my coding skills.   : )

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this helps:**

```
import random

mylist = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

def random_x(a_list):
    sub_list_pick = random.randrange(0, len(a_list))
    element = random.randrange(0, len(mylist[sub_list_pick]))
    a_list[sub_list_pick][element] = "x"
    return a_list

randomed_list = random_x(mylist)

for row in randomed_list:
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 'x', 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```